# Failed prop type: The prop `id` is marked as required in `FormattedMessage`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, mobx, react-intl

I am getting this error in my whole project and I don't know what to do about that. 
It is giving the error even when the component like below is not present in the component.

```
<FormattedMessage {...messages.forexample} />
```

Mobx, react-intl is being used here.

New Edit

The message I am paassing is in the format

```
example: {
       id: "app.components.cartItem.example",
       defaultMessage: 'Items in your cart',
   }
```

Comment: Your `FormattedMessage` Component is not having any prop of `id` Check if the `messages.forexample` you're spreading and passing as `props` has a key of `id` or you post a dummy data of what you're passing into the component

Comment: Looks like You don’t have hot reloading. May be you need to restart the app or may be caching issue. To fix the warning you need to pass id as a prop to FormattedMessage.

Comment: You'd better paste more source codes. It is hard to figure out the problem according to your current post. Maybe the cause has something to do with MobX lazy initializing, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

In your FormattedMessage component, you need to set a default value on id

```
FormattedMessage.defaultProps = {
 id: 0
}
```